# React Use a fetch result in a form (and modify)

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newbie to React and I'm stuck on a problem that seems basic but ...

I'm trying to make a form to update the information of a member.

For that I get a JSON from the back end thanks to FETCH then I display it in the render using TextInput (to be able to modify it)

```
function Judokas() {
 
  const [prenom, onChangePrenom] = useState("c'est moi")
  const [data, onChangeData] = useState([name: ''])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.104:8080/judo/judoka/4427')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        onChangeData(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Fetch Error : ' + err.message)
      })
  }, [])

  // display
  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        <StyledDiv>
          <div>
            <span>nom: </span>
            <span>{data.nom} </span>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={data.nom}
              onChangeText={(val) => {
                data.nom = val
                onChangeData(data)
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>prenom: </span>
            <div>
              <TextInput style={styles.input} value={prenom} onChangeText={onChangePrenom} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </StyledDiv>
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Judokas
```

Any change on the first one (name) is visible in the debugger but there is no change on the display. I don't understand, I think it's related to a "controled input" problem but I can't understand (and can't fix either)
Second one works fine but is not concerned by the usesEffect so it is a problem of interference between usesEffect/

Someone can explain me what is happening and/or correct what is happening.

Thanks

Comment: You’re modifying the state directly.

Comment: Your edit to the data state isn’t valid JS. But if you search the web for “react don’t modify state directly” (it similar, or read the React docs regarding state) it will become more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input} 
  value={data.nom}
  onChangeText={(e) => onChangeData({ nom: e })}
/>
```